# Time Checking in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I'm working on a Calendar app in Python that is checking several events within different parameters. One of the issues I'm having is that in several points of my code I use an example shown below to verify that a particular event is "today".

```
if (eventDateTime - TheCurrentDateTime).days = 0: print "Your event is today."
```

The issue there is that if it's say, Monday and I have an event happening on Tuesday at 8:00A.M. - once it turns to 8:01A.M. Monday morning, the timedelta subtraction check for .days becomes 0, because their are only hours left before the event, not days.  So, being that my Calendar is checking every minute for new updates and such, after that time has past, for the rest of Monday, it continues to report that my Tuesday event is "today."

I'd like to create a multi-condition if statement that somehow keeps it from saying "Your event is today." unless it's past midnight and actually into the next day (day of the event).

Thanks

Comment: Equality is `==`, not `=`. Also, please don't put a single-line body in the same line as the `if` statement.

Comment: The lack of == was a mistake, and the fact that it's single-line body is purely just for example purposes.  None of my code is actually like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just compare date, without time:

```
TheCurrentDate = TheCurrentDateTime.date()
if eventDateTime.date() == TheCurrentDate:
    print "Your event is today."
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(eventDateTime - TheCurrentDateTime).total_seconds() < 86400` to check for "less than 24 hours".

However, for "is today" I'd expect it to compare the actual day, not the number of hours. So compare `eventDateTime.date() == TheCurrentDateTime.date()`

Comment: I think that's exactly what the asker is trying to avoid.

Comment: @DavidRobinson what's the problem if you just convert the seconds? `(24 * 60 * 60)` is just as readable. You can just aswel extend the DateTime with a custom function to do that. So it's not bad :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `timedelta` cannot be extended since it's implemented in C.